# Remove part of number line - aka origin translation in both directions

Tags: python, math

This is such a simple concept, but surprisingly I couldn't find any threads on it. Basically, I'm curious if there's an operator / transformation that effectively removes a portion of the number line centered on zero.

For example, let's say we have a list: `x = [1, 2, -1, -2]` and want to apply the transformation. If the shrink occurs at 1.5, then the output would be `out = [0.0, 0.5, 0.0, -0.5]` does this make sense? Equivalent code is shown below, I'm just curious if there's an actual name for this & an existing operator.

```
    def operator(list, shrinkValue):
        # assume it's numpy list
        sign = np.sign(list)
        list -= sign * shrinkValue # translate towards zero
        idx = (sign * list) < 0.0 # get indices that passed the new zero
        list[idx] = 0.0
        return list
```

Comment: wouldn't shrinking a number by 1.5 such as the number one would result it `-0.5`?

Comment: Not sure about a name, but here's a one line version of it if it helps - `[max(i-s, 0) if i > 0 else min(i+s, 0) for i in x]`

Comment: @Cyzanfar the point is that it gets absorbed into zero

Answer (score 0):

If you don't even know a name for some operation, it seems unlikely to be included in the language; this is the case w/ your curious "shrink and absorb" operation and Python/numpy.